# Is it possible there is a faster way to perform this SELECT query?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, query-optimization

**UPDATE (based on everyone's responses):**

I'm thinking of changing my structure so that I have a new table called prx_tags_sportsitems. I will be removing prx_lists entirely. prx_tags_sportsitems will act as a reference of ID's table to replace the prx_lists.ListString which used to be storing the ID's of tags belonging to each prx_sportsitem.

The new relation will be like so:

- prx_tags_sportsitems.TagID <--> prx_tags.ID
- prx_sportsitems.ID <--> prx_tags_sportsitems.OwnerID

prx_tags will contain the TagName. This is so I can still maintain each "tag" as a separate unique entity.

My new query for finding all sportsitems with the tag "aerobic" will become something similar to as follows:

```
SELECT prx_sportsitems.* FROM prx_sportsitems, prx_tags_sportsitems
WHERE prx_tags_sportsitems.OwnerID = prx_sportsitems.ID 
AND prx_tags_sportsitems.TagID = (SELECT ID FROM prx_tags WHERE TagName = 'aerobic')
ORDER BY prx_sportsitems.DateAdded DESC LIMIT 0,30;
```

Or perhaps I can do something with the "IN" clause, but I'm unsure about that just yet.

Before I go ahead with this huge modification to my scripts, does everyone approve? comments? Many thanks!

**ORIGINAL POST:**

When it comes to MYSQL queries, I'm rather novice. When I originally designed my database I did something, rather silly, because it was the only solution I could find. Now I'm finding it appears to be causing too much stress of my MYSQL server since it takes 0.2 seconds to perform each of these queries where I believe it could be more like 0.02 seconds if it was a better query (or table design if it comes to it!). I want to avoid needing to rebuild my entire site structure since it's deeply designed the way it currently is, so I'm hoping there's a faster mysql query possible.

I have three tables in my database:

1. Sports Items Table
2. Tags Table
3. Lists Table

Each sports item has multiple tag names (categories) assigned to them. Each "tag" is stored as a separate result in prx_tags. I create a "list" in prx_lists for the sports item in prx_sportsitems and link them through prx_lists.OwnerID which links to prx_sportsitems.ID

This is my current query (which finds all sports items which have the tag 'aerobic'):

```
SELECT  prx_sportsitems.* 
FROM    prx_sportsitems, prx_lists 
WHERE   prx_lists.ListString LIKE (CONCAT('%',(SELECT prx_tags.ID 
                                               FROM prx_tags
                                               WHERE prx_tags.TagName = 'aerobic'
                                               limit 0,1),'#%')) 
 AND    prx_lists.ListType = 'Tags-SportsItems' 
 AND    prx_lists.OwnerID = prx_sportsitems.ID
 ORDER BY prx_sportsitems.DateAdded
 DESC LIMIT 0,30
```

To help clarify more, the list that contains all of the tag ids is inside a single field called ListString and I structure it like so: " #1 #2 #3 #4 #5" ...and from that, the above query "concats" the prx_tags.ID which tagname is 'aerobic'.

My thoughts are that, there probably isn't a faster query existing and that I need to simply accept I need to do something simpler, such as putting all the Tags in a list, directly inside prx_sportsitems in a new field called "TagsList" and then I can simply run a query which does Select * from prx_sportsitems Where TagsList LIKE '%aerobic%' - however, I want to avoid needing to redesign my entire site. I'm really regretting not looking into optimization beforehand :(

Comment: Wait . . . You're concatenating the ID numbers for tags, and storing all those id numbers in a single string in prx_lists.ListString? Is that right?

Comment: PS - still waiting for someone to review my update? thanks

Comment: This is a big improvement on the original query.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever I am writing a query, and think I need to use `LIKE`, an alarm goes off in my head that maybe there is a better design.  This is certainly the case here.

You need to redesign the `prx_lists` tables.  From what you've said, its hard to say what the exact schema should be, but here is my best guess:

`prx_lists` should have three columns: `OwnerID`, `ListType`, and `TagName`.  Then you would have one row for each tag an OwnerID has.  Your above query would now look something like this:

```
SELECT prx_sportsitems.*
FROM prx_sportsitems, prx_lists
where prx_lists.TagName = 'aerobic'
      AND prx_lists.OwnerID = prx_sportsitems.ID
```

This is a MUCH more efficient query.  Maybe `ListType` doesn't belong in that table either, but its hard to say without more info about what that column is used for.

Don't forget to [create the appropriate indexes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm) either!  This will improve performance.

Refactoring your database schema might be painful, but its seems to me the only way to fix your long term problem.

Comment: +1 for the refactoring comment. It may be painful now, but if you are continuing to develop this system it will be MORE painful and probably necessary later.

Comment: +1 just read your answer and it was what I was going for by refactoring the `%aerobic%` away and creating a new table - this would then be referenced by a common id (more sense in a relational database than doing a like into space delimited field).

Comment: Also consider removing the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` and doing the sort in code - generally much faster if the number of results is <1000.

Comment: -1 for Yzmir (If it were only possible) - Let the DB do it's job (sorting, filtering). Don't reinvent the wheel and assume yours will be faster.

Comment: I understand your concept and I am considering something like this for a future fixup. That will be a major overhaul and probably take me weeks to months to fix everything but it will be worth it performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

> To help clarify more, the list that
>   contains all of the tag ids is inside
>   a single field called ListString and I
>   structure it like so: " #1 #2 #3 #4 #5" ...and from that, the above query "concats" the prx_tags.ID which
>   tagname is 'aerobic'.

There's your problem right there. Don't store delimited data in a DB field (ListString). Modeling data this way is going to make it extremely difficult/impossible to write performant queries against it.

**Suggestion:** Break the contents of ListString out into a related table with one row for each item.

Comment: Well, the reasoning I had was because I had to store data in different formats so I thought why not stored it as a list and assign a "List Type" (eg. prx_lists.ListType = 'Tags-SportsItems'). I recognize it is a very poor approach though, especially when you have lots of users on your system. Thanks for your suggestion. I will be looking into this.

Comment: When designing databases you will do best if you follow the rule: One item per row, one attribute per column.

Comment: Silly question I'm sure but: What if there are an unknown or variable amount of attributes per item?

Comment: Then you would have 0..X rows in the related table. They key is that any multi-valued entity or attribute is represented by a table, not a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't make any changes without
   looking at the [execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html). (And
   post that here, too, by editing your
   original question.)
2. The way your LIKE clause is
   constructed, MySQL can't use an
   index.
3. The LIKE clause is a symptom. Your
   table structure is more likely the problem.

You'll probably get at least one order of magnitude improvement by building sane tables.

> I'm really regretting not looking into
>   optimization beforehand

That's not what caused your problem. Being ignorant of the fundamentals of database design caused your problem. (That's an observation, not a criticism. You can fix ignorance. You can't fix stupid.)

**Later**:

Post your [existing table structure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) and your proposed changes. You'll be a lot happier with our ability to predict what your code will do than with our ability to predict what your description of a piece of your code will do.

Comment: Unfortunately it is my stupid that caused the problem since I designed everything while I was learning php and mysql. I just did everything trial and error. This is part of my trial and error :P but yeah it is a costly part! Thanks for your steps. I am going to overlook some other places I may have used LIKE clause, although I do think the LIKE clause has its use for things eg. a search engine. I'll be writing up a plan and hopefully post it here too, but since I have other priorities and the scope of the overall changes needed, unfortunately that may be quite a while!

Comment: Actually I've written out my plan as you suggested by editing my question. If you could review it I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Your ignorance, not your stupidity. There's nothing inherently wrong with the LIKE operator. It's just that it's easy to write LIKE predicates that make indexes useless.

Comment: Thanks. Catcall, could you review my update? I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: @Catcall: I haven't done any new structures yet. It's as simple as I described it though. I suppose I'm already confident in my new plan anyhow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> the list that contains all of the tag ids is inside a single field called ListString and I structure it like so: " #1 #2 #3 #4 #5" ...and from that, the above query "concats" the prx_tags.ID which tagname is 'aerobic'.

Not only is that bad, storing denormalized data, but the separator character is uncommon.

### Interim Improvement

The quickest way to improve things is to change the separator character you're currently using ("#") to a comma:

```
UPDATE PRX_LISTS
   SET liststring = REPLACE(liststring, '#', ',')
```

Then, you can use [MySQL's FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
  SELECT si.* 
    FROM PRX_SPORTSITEMS si
    JOIN PRX_LISTS l ON l.ownerid = si.id
    JOIN PRX_TAGS t ON FIND_IN_SET(t.id, l.liststring) > 0 
   WHERE t.tagname = 'aerobic'
     AND l.listtype = 'Tags-SportsItems' 
ORDER BY si.DateAdded DESC 
   LIMIT 0, 30
```

### Long Term Solution

As you've experienced, searching for specifics in denormalized data does not perform well, and makes queries overly complicated.  You need to change the `PRX_LISTS` table so one row contains a unique combination of the `SPORTSITEM.ownerid` and `PRX_TAGS.id`, and whatever other columns you might need.  I'd recommend renaming as well - lists of what, exactly?  The name is too generic:

```
CREATE TABLE SPORTSITEM_TAGS_XREF (
   sportsitem_ownerid INT,
   tag_id INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (sportsitem_ownerid INT, tag_id)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the interim solution. I'll possibly look into implementing the long term solutions you have all kindly written out for me. By the way, I named it "lists" but I also assigned each row a "ListType" value. prx_lists was meant to store complicated arrays of values without needing thousands of new records for one individual owner (OwnerID). It worked and seemed more efficient to a learner like me at the time, but that was a major oversight.